# Get photos by Geo coordinates

Tags: mobli

I'm using Mobli api for my application and look for EndPoint for getting all the public photos according to Geo coordinates (and this is the only parameter I want to use. not search query or any other parameters).

Any Ides?

Comment: Please publish relevant portions from your code if you want a real help and not only mental support